# ANCS Notifications in Core Bluetooth Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ancs

I am working with a BLE device which shows all the notifications received on my iOS device. I have set up all the ANCS part form the BLE Device side and it is working successfully.
I am trying to implement a functionality which will include the use of a switch in the settings screen named as "Allow notifications".
As the name suggest, If switched off then the ANCS notifications should not transfer from my device to the BLE device.
This approach is being taken so as the micro controller has to process a lot less information in case the notifications are off.

Please suggest a way if anything is possible from iOS side as we do not have any control over the ANCS notification in Core Bluetooth framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way will be to send a command over BLE from the iOS device to the BLE Device to "STOP" listening for ACNS. You could send a special notification class you use for commands to stop listening. You could then re-enable delivery by sending a "GO" command to the BLE Device.

This way you can turn off and on the ability of the BLE Device to listen or not to the ANCS from iOS.